# How to send a PDF as fax from windows command line

Tags: windows, fax

How can I send a PDF file from command line in Windows to a windows fax? Of course the receiving faxno should be entered from command line.

I'm looking for something like:

```
c:\>FaxPdf test.pdf 044231134
```

Update: And no, printing is not enough, since when you use printing the faxno has to be entered manually and it should be given on the command line instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing from Windows 7 command line](http://superuser.com/questions/477895/printing-from-windows-7-command-line)

Comment: Given that sending a fax uses a printer, its a duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/477895/printing-from-windows-7-command-line

Comment: And how do I enter the receiving fax number when using printing?

Comment: A quick google search lead me to a windows component called wfs.exe which can be started from the commandline.

Comment: LPChip that would be cool - with knowing the exe Name I found something, but no Explanation how to enter a faxno. And it does not seem to work with pdfs?

Comment: [Windows Fax And Scan Command Line Options?](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/windows-fax-and-scan-command-line-options.3068451/)

Comment: @DavidPostill - no way to enter the faxno from command line :(

Comment: To those voting to close as a duplicate, the Windows Fax may work like a printer driver, but this question has the added requirement of adding a fax number and doing it in the command line.  The proposed duplicate does not address that.  You might be able to incorporate a reference to the other question in an answer that provides the additional detail if it is possible to do this.