# How to bulk printing of printer-friendly HTML to PDF?

Tags: printing, html, print-to-pdf

There are several websites like [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson7.html) that are printer-friendly by removing unnecessary things, and a lot of them I download using either HTTrack or wget, and then change to PDF manually. But lately I have been having problem with large volume of HTML getting piled up.

Are there any programs which can do this?

I have tried using several bulk-printing tools, like [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) and sourceforge-project html-to-pdf (I couldn't even get this to running, I couldn't find ABCpdf v7 but when I installed v8 it asked for v7 again.) but these render all the graphics and then print.

If possible, cross-platform is preferred. I am okay with it being command-line tool.

I am considering to use AutoHotKey or something similar just for this if there is no solution.

Comment: You can try this for printing through command line : http://superuser.com/questions/477895/printing-from-windows-7-command-line

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried both `print` and `notepad /p` commands but both didn't work. When using `print`, it said the document was printing but it came neither on the queue nor any new files were created.
And with `notepad /p` option, the pdf printed was the actual html code.

Comment: Last suggestion I have is to try something like this: https://sites.google.com/site/torisugari/commandlineprint2