# I need a command in cmd to print a page

Tags: command-line, printer, network-printer

I need to print a page through command prompt. Is there any file which I can use to do it. I don't have any right now.

Comment: please specify more in detail, what page to print? sending some text type information to a printer can be done by piping it to the printer e.g. with powershell's `out-printer`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing from Windows 7 command line](https://superuser.com/questions/477895/printing-from-windows-7-command-line)

Comment: It is possible to print from the Windows command line, but we need to know a) what kind of document you are printing and b) what kind of printer. In some cases even COPY or PRINT (both DOS commands) can be used to print.